# GRASS GIS Windows 8.1 error

Tags: error, grass-7.2

So I am a new user with GRASS 7.2, in Windows, and the problem was when I first booted GRASS GIS, I had to create a new location, for my data, but every time I was trying to create that location GRASS would either

Crash

[image]

or popup an empty error

[image]

Is there a way to resolve that, or do I need to install an older version of GRASS?
.

Comment: I recommend a clean installation of the latest LTS version of Qgis (Qgis 2.18).
I've solved this way.

Comment: Why did it worked. I mean it worked for me, but why?

Comment: You have received an error exception. Specifically, the error code is c0000135, this generally happens when a .dll file is not found during the installation procedure, or there is something that does not go to a registry key.
By re-installing Qgis, the scripting procedure has been restarted and, by choosing a stable version like 2.18, you have decreased the probability of the error occurring again.